# How can you automatically remove trailing whitespace in vim

Tags: vim, automation, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am getting 'trailing whitespace' errors trying to commit some files in Git.

I want to remove these trailing whitespace characters automatically right before I save Python files.

Can you configure Vim to do this? If so, how?

Comment: this doesn't concern python alone

Comment: Use my [DeleteTrailingWhitespace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) plugin.

Comment: Related: [What's the simplest way to strip trailing whitespace from all lines in a file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/454/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 225, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces#Automatically_removing_all_trailing_whitespace).

Adding the following to my .vimrc file did the trick:

```vim
autocmd BufWritePre *.py :%s/\s\+$//e
```

The `e` flag at the end means that the command doesn't issue an error message if the search pattern fails. See [`:h :s_flags`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As_flags) for more.

Comment: Interesting! Trailing white space is a battle at work. I loathe it, others don't understand why. We use as much vi as vim (I use vim; they don't because they'd have to install it). I have a program I call stb to Strip Trailing Blanks and I use that as a filter; works in vi too. This is better.

Comment: This changes cursor position on each save. Is is possible to avoid it?

Comment: OK, I've found, answer is below.

Comment: Since this is the de facto answer for this question maybe it should be updated to maintain cursor position.

Comment: see too keepjumps :h keepjumps

Comment: You could upvote the better answer until it become the best first one presented.

Comment: This do changes the cursor position on each save, however, a simple `gi` will put you back on the previous cursor position.

Comment: Using `:%!sed -r 's/\s+$//'` as the command seems to be another way (besides `keepjumps`) to prevent moving the cursor. See `:h filter`.

Comment: `gi` jumps to the last position where text was inserted (not always the cursor position before the `:%s` command) and `:%!sed -r 's/\s+$//'` jumps to the beginning of the file. I don't get how `keepjumps` is supposed to be used, `:keepjumps :%s/\s+$//e` doesn't seem to do anything different. I'm using `:%s/\s\+$//e|normal ''` and it seems to work as I expect (goes to the cursor position before using the `:%s` command).

Comment: Correction for my previous comment: `:%s/\s\+$//e|normal ''` will jump to the wrong position if no trailing whitespaces were found.

Comment: This will also delete trailing spaces in multi-line strings, which may not be desired in some cases. But I guess there is no easy way to avoid this?

Comment: Maybe you could explicit that the `e` at the end means, if we did not find the pattern, vi does not consider the substitute command as failed

Answer (score 183):

Compilation of above plus saving cursor position:

```vim
function! <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
  if !&binary && &filetype != 'diff'
    let l:save = winsaveview()
    keeppatterns %s/\s\+$//e
    call winrestview(l:save)
  endif
endfun

autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,php,ruby,python autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
```

If you want to apply this on save to any file, leave out the second `autocmd` and use a wildcard `*`:

```
autocmd BufWritePre,FileWritePre,FileAppendPre,FilterWritePre *
  \ :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
```

Comment: You could better your function by also saving the last search and restoring it.

let _s=@/
let @/=_s

Comment: For other noobs like me this is how you limit the files the function is called on:

Comment: Pure awesome.  I use vim but am too lazy to look stuff up like this usually.  This gave me a way to automate applying my arsenal of regexes on save.  I'm stuck using Ruby for now, so I love not having to cut & paste my hash-rocket-killing regex.:wa

Comment: I removed the ``autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,php,ruby,python `` part to make it apply to all files.

Comment: I can't figure out why col(".") always returns 1 for me.

Comment: I had to add *. before each file extension.

Comment: @xApple: Inside functions, saving and restoring the last search is not necessary - leaving the function context will take care of that.

Comment: @swt83 you need to also replace `<buffer>` with `*` if you want it to work on all files

Comment: Is there any good reason to only limit this to certain file types?

Comment: If you prefix the substitute command w/ `keepp`, it will not alter your search history, i.e. `keepp %s/\s\+$//e`

Comment: Add an `undojoin` to stop this from polluting your undo history:

`autocmd BufWritePre * undojoin | :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()`

Comment: Add `\m` to the pattern to be independent of the *magic* option. Save position better with `let l:save = winsaveview()` and `call winrestview(l:save)`. Add `if !&binary && &filetype != 'diff'` to ignore on binary and diff files (E.g. patch file to remove white spaces).

Answer (score 70):

I also usually have a :

```
match Todo /\s\+$/
```

in my `.vimrc` file, so that end of line whitespace are hilighted.

Todo being a syntax hilighting [group-name](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#group-name) that is used for hilighting keywords like `TODO`, `FIXME` or `XXX`. It has an annoyingly ugly yellowish background color, and I find it's the best to hilight things you **don't** want in your code :-)

Comment: Or you can set list and set listchars+=trail:.

Comment: Excellent - it's the perfect middle ground between automatically removing trailing whitespace (even when I may not be aware of it, or when it's someone else's code that I'm just happening to work in the same file with), to not doing anything about it. Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, my favorite color scheme zenburn doens't highlight

Comment: @PeterLong, doesn't work in railscasts theme either. Check it with `:hi Todo`. So I perused `:hi <Tab>` and `:help hi`. I considered `Cursor` and `Error`, but I think I'll try `match VisualNOS /\s\+$/
`. I might combine this with some of the `autocmd`s from other answers here.

Answer (score 56):

I both highlight existing trailing whitespace and also strip trailing whitespace.

I configure my editor (vim) to show white space at the end, e.g.

[image]

with this at the bottom of my .vimrc:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

and I 'auto-strip' it from files when saving them, in my case *.rb for ruby files, again in my ~/.vimrc

```
function! TrimWhiteSpace()
    %s/\s\+$//e
endfunction
autocmd BufWritePre     *.rb :call TrimWhiteSpace()
```

Comment: Great! Thanks!, I specially like the function.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a way to filter by more than one FileType.

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,python,ruby,java autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> :%s/\s\+$//e
```

Comment: Every File: autocmd FileType * autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> :%s/\s\+$//e

Answer (score 10):

I saw this solution in a comment at 
[VIM Wikia - Remove unwanted spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces#Automatically_removing_all_trailing_whitespace)

I really liked it. Adds a `.` on the unwanted white spaces.

[image]

## Put this in your `.vimrc`

```
" Removes trailing spaces
function TrimWhiteSpace()
  %s/\s*$//
  ''
endfunction

set list listchars=trail:.,extends:>
autocmd FileWritePre * call TrimWhiteSpace()
autocmd FileAppendPre * call TrimWhiteSpace()
autocmd FilterWritePre * call TrimWhiteSpace()
autocmd BufWritePre * call TrimWhiteSpace()
```

Answer (score 8):

Copied and pasted from http://blog.kamil.dworakowski.name/2009/09/unobtrusive-highlighting-of-trailing.html (the link no longer works, but the bit you need is below)

"This has the advantage of not highlighting each space you type at the end of the line, only when you open a file or leave insert mode. Very neat."

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
au ColorScheme * highlight ExtraWhitespace guibg=red
au BufEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
au InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
au InsertLeave * match ExtraWhiteSpace /\s\+$/
```

Comment: The blog link seems to have died.

Comment: The same solution is found at the [this link](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) under "Using the match command".

Answer (score 5):

This is how I'm doing it. I can't remember where I stole it from tbh.

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :call <SID>StripWhite()
fun! <SID>StripWhite()
    %s/[ \t]\+$//ge
    %s!^\( \+\)\t!\=StrRepeat("\t", 1 + strlen(submatch(1)) / 8)!ge
endfun
```

Comment: Hum, that's pretty dangerous to do it on "*" if you eventually open up binary files, they may end up in a pretty bad shape.

Comment: Yeah probably not the smartest, then again I don't use vim for a hex editor either. That won't execute unless you save.

Comment: I think this beats the alternative of listing every single file type that you might work on, no? I work on rb, php, cs, html, sass, css, js, coffee, xml, xslt, pl, etc, etc, etc... Is there a happy medium?

Comment: Unless you're writing to binary files in vim this probably won't ever be a issue.

Comment: It appears in the first `%s` the global (g) flag is as useless as a space at EOL :-)

Answer (score 3):

A solution which simply strips trailing whitespace from the file is not acceptable in all circumstances. It will work in a project which has had this policy from the start, and so there are no such whitespace that you did not just add yourself in your upcoming commit.

Suppose you wish merely not to add new instances of trailing whitespace, without affecting existing whitespace in lines that you didn't edit, in order to keep your commit free of changes which are irrelevant to your work.

In that case, with git, you can can use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e # bail on errors

git stash save commit-cleanup
git stash show -p | sed '/^\+/s/ *$//' | git apply
git stash drop
```

That is to say, we stash the changes, and then filter all the `+` lines in the diff to remove their trailing whitespace as we re-apply the change to the working directory. If this command pipe is successful, we drop the stash.

Answer (score 2):

For people who want to run it for specific file types (FileTypes are not always reliable):

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.c,*.cpp,*.cc,*.h,*.hpp,*.py,*.m,*.mm :%s/\s\+$//e
```

Or with vim7:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.{c,cpp,cc,h,hpp,py,m,mm} :%s/\s\+$//e
```

Answer (score 1):

The other approaches here somehow didn't work for me in MacVim when used in the `.vimrc` file. So here's one that does and highlights trailing spaces:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set listchars=trail:·
set list
```

Comment: Executing `set listchars=trail:·` saying: `E474: Invalid argument: listchars=trail:·`. Can you validate your example?

Comment: @kenorb see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321538/vim-error-e474-invalid-argument-listchars-tab-trail

Answer (score 1):

If you trim whitespace, you should *only* do it on files that are already clean.  "When in Rome...".  This is good etiquette when working on codebases where spurious changes are unwelcome.

This function detects trailing whitespace and turns on trimming only if it was already clean.

The credit for this idea goes to a gem of a comment here:  https://github.com/atom/whitespace/issues/10  (longest bug ticket comment stream ever)

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.test call KarlDetectWhitespace()

fun! KarlDetectWhitespace()
python << endpython
import vim
nr_unclean = 0
for line in vim.current.buffer:
    if line.rstrip() != line:
        nr_unclean += 1

print "Unclean Lines: %d" % nr_unclean
print "Name: %s" % vim.current.buffer.name
cmd = "autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call KarlStripTrailingWhitespace()"
if nr_unclean == 0:
    print "Enabling Whitespace Trimming on Save"
    vim.command(cmd)
else:
    print "Whitespace Trimming Disabled"
endpython
endfun

fun! KarlStripTrailingWhitespace()
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    %s/\s\+$//e
    call cursor(l, c)
endfun
```

Comment: You could also keep search register `let _s=@/` and restore it at the end `    let @/=_s` .In this case we are using black hole register

Answer (score 1):

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.py execute 'norm m`' | %s/\s\+$//e | norm g``
```

This will keep the cursor in the same position as it was just before saving

Answer (score 0):

`autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//<CR>:let @/=''<CR>`