# How to repeat the same search and replace command over disjunct line ranges in Vim?

Tags: vim, replace

I had a situation where I wanted to replace `FOO` with `BAR` through out a file. However, I only want to do it in certain places, say, between lines 68–104, 500–537, and 1044–1195. In practice, I dropped markers at the lines of interest (via `ma`, `mb`, `mc`, etc.) and ran the following:

```
:'a,'b s/FOO/BAR/g | 'c,'d s/FOO/BAR/g | 'e,'f s/FOO/BAR/g
```

I had to repeat this dozens of times with different search and replace terms `s/CAT/DOG`, etc., and it became a pain to have to rewrite the command line each time. I was lucky in that I had only three places that I needed to confine my search to (imagine how messy the command line would get if there were 30 or 40).

Short of writing a function, is there any neater way of doing this?

On a related note. I copied `FOO` to the `s` (search) register, and `BAR` to the `r` (replace) and tried running

```
:'a,'b s/\=@s/\=@r/ | 'c,'d s/\=@s/\=@r/ | 'e,'f s/\=@s/\=@r/
```

This would have saved me having to rewrite the command line each time, but, alas, it didn’t work. The replace bit `\=@r` was fine, but the `\=@s` bit in the search pattern gave me an error.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You can also use CONTROL-P and CONTROL-N (I think) to cycle through previous commands. This should eliminate the need to re-type commands.

Comment: it is usual to accept an answer, if it was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to perform a set of line-wise operations (like substitutions) on a bunch of different ranges of lines, one trick you can use is to make those lines look different by first adding a prefix (that isn't shared by any of the other lines).

The way I usually do this is to indent the entire file with something like `>G` performed on the first line, and then use either `:s/^ /X/` commands or block-visual to replace the leading spaces with X on the lines I want.

Then use `:g` in conjunction with `:s`. eg:

```
:%g/^X/s/FOO/BAR/g
:%g/^X/s/BAZ/QUUX/g
```

Finally, remove the temporary prefixes.

Comment: I see what you're at - putting a temporary mark in the first column for each line in my range. That's a great idea thanks. (Unfortunately it wouldn't work in this case as the text file was source code, and I wanted to compile as I went along.)

Comment: You could have put an comment at every line ending to distinguish the code lines, which should not interfere with compilation.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get rid of the necessity to retype the same search
pattern, substitution string and flags, one can simply use the
`:&` command with the `&` flag:

```
:'a,'bs/pat/str/g | 'c,'d&& | 'e,'f&&
```

(See `:help :&` for details.)

Comment: :& is a new one on me. Thanks, it will come in very handy.

Comment: @Dave:  It is handy indeed.  If I understand the question correctly, using the `:&` command solves the stated issue, doesn't it?

Comment: In the example I gave, yes it is perfect thanks. However, if I had many locations that I wanted to search I think that @eipson-2-halbe's answer might be more practical. Say I had 40 locations, then sourcing an external text file might be more manageable that putting 40 'xxx,'yyy&& entries on the command line. A combination of both of your methods is probably the way to go!

Comment: @Dave:  I see.  By the way, are said locations completely arbitrary?  Or they could be derived somehow from the surrounding text?

Comment: In this case it was easier to manually mark the boundries (or make a mental note of the line numbers). I could have written a regex to seek out the boundaries, but that would have been overkill.

Comment: @Dave:  I would recommend you to make particular details about that boundaries known.  It may be that there is a simple method for automatically detecting them.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using marker use this one :

`:68,104s/FOO/BAR/g << substitue from line 68 to 104`

This should make your job a little bit easier and clearer.

Answer (score 3):

inspired by @Vdt's answer:

I am not sure but you could write all the substitutions down in a file and source that file i think.
`substitutions.vim`:

```
68,104s/FOO/BAR/g
168,204s/FOO/BAR/g
618,644s/FOO/BAR/g
681,1014s/FOO/BAR/g
.
.
.
68,104s/BAZ/BOOO/g
168,204s/BAZ/BOOO/g
```

and then `:so substitutions.vim` maybe you can also use this for multiple files of same structure. you can add an `e` to add an ignore error message, if it is not clear that the substitutions are found on the corresponding line blocks.

Comment: Yes, that would have worked as well. I didn't know the 'e' flag - thanks.

Comment: for the `e` i have to give props to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146763/about-a-key-binding-to-remove-trailing-spaces-and-save/11146887#11146887 this answer by @pb2q

Comment: p.s. I've just tried this on a test file, and it works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With `q:`, you can recall previous command lines and edit them as a normal Vim buffer, so you can quickly replace `FOO` and `BAR` with something else, then re-execute the line with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The `s/\=@s/\=@r/` doesn't work; as you said, this only works in the replacement part. But for the pattern, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> to insert the contents of register s, instead of `\=@s`. Preferably use the default register, then it's a simple `s//`, but you probably know that already.

Answer (score 2):

When performed over a closed fold, substitutions are limited to that fold.

1. fold each region
2. put the cursor on one closed fold
3. perform the substitution: `:s/foo/bar<CR>`
4. move to the next closed fold with `zj` or `zk`
5. use the command-line history: `:<C-p><CR>` or `:<Up><CR>` to perform the same substitution
6. repeat…

You can also add the `c` flag at the end of your substitution so that Vim asks you for a confirmation before actually performing it. This can be tedious if you have lot of matches.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest way to do it

```
:5,10s/old/new/g
```

5,10 : startlinenum,endlinenum