# How to delete to the last blank characters on the line

Tags: vim

I have:

```
  int x = 1;______
```

(underscores means spaces)
and I would like to get:

```
  int x = 1;
```

My naive solution is `$bld$`, is there a quickest way?

In Emacs I use `M-\ (delete-horizontal-space)`

Comment: See also [How can you automatically remove trailing whitespace in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356126/how-can-you-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-vim)

Comment: @doubleDown It's a sequence of key presses. $ moves the cursor to the end of the line, b moves the cursor to the end of the previous word, l moves the cursor one character to the right and d$ deletes everything from the cursor to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this with a search and replace mapping:

```
map <leader>W :%s/\s\+$//<CR>:let @/=''<CR>
```

`:%s/\s\+$//` deletes all trailing white space and then `:let @/=''` clears the search register.

Answer (score 2):

For the current line:

```
:s/\s\+$
```

For all lines:

```
:%s/\s\+$
```

The substitution text can be omitted if blank, so we don't need to write `s/\s\+$//`.

Comment: `\+` is more efficient than `*`; it will mean that only lines with trailing whitespace will get altered, rather than every line.

Comment: I'd put it much stronger. `*` is simply a bad idea. Try `u` after it: every line has been modified, rather than just the lines which have actually been altered. Makes it hard to see what changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/\s\+$//
```

What it does is it searches for white spaces at the end of the line and replace them by nothing.

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces