# Vim Error: E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:»·,trail:·

Tags: vim

**Summary:**

I am receiving the following error for having the below line in my .vimrc file

**Error:**

```
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:»·,trail:·
```

**.vimrc:**

```
set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·
```

I have researched this and it appears to have something to do with UTF-8 encoding being properly set.

**System Setup:**

lsb_release:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=en_US
```

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/556915/how-to-let-vim-listchar-work-under-not-utf8-environment

Comment: That locale setup doesn't make much sense. You have $LANG set to en_US.UTF-8, but then you override it for everything and even set $LC_ALL which will override the other $LC_* variables.

Comment: Mabey `locale.conf` is not right: `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 locale > /etc/locale.conf`

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**Solution:**

Place the following lines at the top of the .vimrc the error mentions:

**.vimrc:**

```
scriptencoding utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, `:h scriptsncoding` says that: _If you set the `encoding` option in your `.vimrc`, `:scriptencoding` must be placed after that. Should these two lines be the other way around?

Answer (score 24):

None of the other solutions worked for me.

My `listchars` looks like this:

```
listchars=eol:~,tab:>.,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:_
```

The problem was that my Vim is too old for the `space:` parameter in `listchars`. As we can read in [this post](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/E474-Invalid-argument-listchars-eol-tab-trail-extends-precedes-space-tp5727113p5727116.html) (I modified the quote to make it more readable):

> `space:` was added to `listchars` in `v7.4.710` on 2015-04-21 by Bram. 
>   The stock Debian install of Vim doesn't offer `space:`.

The removal of the trailing `,space:_` solves the problem.

---

### But wait! I want my vimrc to be portable

Well, as  [816-8055](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973409/816-8055) suggests you might use `if has()` in your vimrc:

```
if has("patch-7.4.710")
    listchars=eol:~,tab:>.,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:_
else
    listchars=eol:~,tab:>.,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
endif
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me. I'm now using `if has("patch-7.4.710")` in my *.vimrc* because I have different versions on different systems.

Answer (score 8):

Just placing `set encoding=utf8` anywhere in my _vimrc, but before `set lcs=tab:>-,trail:·,nbsp:·,extends:>,precedes:<` solved it

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I spelled `encoding` properly ;)

Answer (score 6):

Not a real solution to your specific problem, but another (non-utf8-safe) way might be just to use ASCII chars, like this:

```
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:.,precedes:<,extends:>
```

If you have UTF-8 available, Justins solution is the better one of course.

Comment: Nice, but this only lets me see that it doesn't work here. Then I realised that `set list` is needed somewhere before this line.

Answer (score 1):

The tab character should be of the form `XY` i.e. two characters. Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27723254).

Comment: In OP's example, it already is: X='»' and Y='·'

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the problem here, but may help others with the same error: if your values include a space, you must escape it so vim doesn't parse the list as separate arguments.

```
:set listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:~,...
```