# vim-airline: what is "! trailing[1]"

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-airline

At the right of my vim-airline display, I have `! trailing[1]`.

I'm assuming this means trailing whitespace of some sort, but how do I read what vim-airline is telling me and what am I supposed to do?

Comment: It means you have trailing whitespace on line 1, and you could, um, delete it? Or ignore it, or turn off the check :)

Comment: Check these posts on removing trailing whitespace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356126/how-can-you-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-vim#356130

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That means you have a trailing whitespace on the first line (`[1]`).

You can add to your `.vimrc` the following:

```
set list          " Display unprintable characters f12 - switches
set listchars=tab:•\ ,trail:•,extends:»,precedes:« " Unprintable chars mapping
```

That'll display whitespace chars. You can toggle it with `:set invlist`.

Answer (score 18):

Airline is telling you that on *line 1* you have trailing whitespace, which is usually something you want to get rid of.

So go to the line and delete it (`1G$gelD`).

It’s a good feature, but you can turn it on/off with:

```
:AirlineToggleWhitespace
```

More info on [trailing whitespace here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces).

Comment: Is there a way to have it always turned off?

Comment: How does one add this to their vimrc?

Answer (score 8):

To turn off the trailing whitespace check at startup, add to your vimrc:

`let g:airline#extensions#whitespace#enabled = 0`