# Turn off remove trailing whitespace for Vim

Tags: vim

I like to use vim's auto formatting command but it is causing a problem with me and my boss.  At some point someone's editor added blank lines with spaces.  When i run `gg=G` it removes that whitespace and is creating a bunch of noise in my git commits.  I still want to be able to format the text but I don't want whitespace removed.

This seems like I need to change a setting somewhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/356130/10577

Comment: He put it in .vimrc, but it could also be in filetype.vim

Comment: That link is to remove trailing whitespace.  I want it to stay when i format a page.

Comment: Well, I was thinking that if that was the problem, you could find that statement and remove it, because that's the only thing I know of that removes whitespace automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in option that you can simply set. The closest is *autoformatting*; with `a` and `w` in `'formatoptions'`, Vim will format as you type, and keep a single trailing space at the end of each line belonging to a paragraph. But that doesn't preserve existing trailing whitespace.

If you need to reindent and reformat with `gg=G`, that implies that the existing layout is pretty broken. Most people will argue that you shouldn't care about preserving trailing whitespace (itself a bad practice, and usually flagged by Git) in that case.

If you can, limit the scope of the `=` command, e.g. by applying it selectively only on few (bad) lines, or the visual selection. That will reduce the noise in commits.

If you really need to reformat while preserving trailing whitespace, I would open a diff inside Vim (using Git, the [Fugitive plugin](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975) makes this very easy), and then manually edit the trailing spaces back in. The effort required in this should further convince you (and your team) that a bit more care about proper editing hygiene benefits everybody :-)